# Django serializer display BooleanField of related model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### Context

I have 2 models: `App` & `AppVersion`.

I am trying to serialize fields from `AppVersion` along with a field from the `App` model. I am unable to display the related field in my serializer.

### Goal

My goal is to have the API response include the related field like this:

```
[
    {
        "app_version_uuid": "61ee8efa-f79e-4fcd-a6ea-4a33544442e1",
        "app_version_name": "Test app version",
        "version_code": 2,
        "version_name": "0.2",
        "auto_start": True   # related field
    }
]
```

### Models

```
# models.py

class App(models.Model):
    app_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    package_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    auto_start = models.BooleanField(default=False)  


class AppVersion(models.Model):
    app_version_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    app_uuid = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app_versions')
    app_version_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100, editable=False)
    version_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

### Serializers

```
# serializers.py

class AppVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auto_start = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='auto_start')

    class Meta:
        model = AppVersion
        fields = ('app_version_uuid', 'app_version_name', 'version_code', 'version_name', 'auto_start')
```

### What I tried

I tried to use the `SlugRelatedField()` as shown in my `serializers.py`. I also tried to use a `SerializerMethodField()` like this:

```
# serializers.py

class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = ('auto_start')

class AppVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auto_start = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_auto_start(self, model):
        return AppSerializer(model).data

    class Meta:
        model = AppVersion
        fields = ('app_version_uuid', 'app_version_name', 'version_code', 'version_name', 'auto_start')
```

The `SlugRelatedField()` does not show the `auto_start` in the response.

Using the `SerializerMethodField()` `auto_start` is shown as:

```
"auto_start": {}
```

What do I need to change in order to get the related field `auto_start` in my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`source`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument along with [**`BooleanField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#booleanfield),

```
class AppVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auto_start = serializers.BooleanField(source='app_uuid.auto_start')

    class Meta:
        model = AppVersion
        fields = ('app_version_uuid', 'app_version_name', 'version_code', 'version_name', 'auto_start')
```